# JS: ArrayBuffer of Unknown Size

Tags: javascript, buffer, arraybuffer

I have a big object that I want to store in an ArrayBuffer (let say Uint8Array). Note: I do not know how big the object is.

I already have all the logic about setting the values in the buffer. (It is already working if I use `new Uint8Array(100000000);` for example.)

The problem is that I don't know if resizing a buffer efficiently is possible. Performance is the main preoccupation here.

I've been thinking starting with let say `new Uint8Array(100);` and if I need more, I create a new one with double the size `new Uint8Array(200);` and copy the existing content on the new one (not quite sure how). And so on.

What about just creating a regular array and converting it at the end into a `Uint8Array`?

Comment: how many of these arrays do you need at once?

Comment: Only 1. I do create many of them every second but only 1 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one at a time but still many per time and have a need for speed, you need to keep the first array and overwrite it. You can work out the amount of memory you need for the first one as you described (it is not that slow) but keep the array for the next ones (you'll need something to keep the current length). Every time you need more, you do as you did with the first one. You might want to "free" the memory from time to time when it gets too large.

It is a poor-man's `malloc()`/ garbage collector, yes, and it assumes that your need of arrays is *strictly* consecutive.

Comment: But that means small data would use a big array size. I'm sending the data to the client so it needs to stay small.

Comment: I'm sorry but you cannot have it both (at least not *now*, a kind of `realloc()` for these special arrays is planned for the near future). You either get it fast **or** small. It is not strictly binary, so you can play a bit with the knobs but you cannot eat the cake and keep it, too. And also: are you *sure*, that is have you run a proper profiling session such that you know for sure that the array handling is by far(!) the biggest bottleneck? Oh, and if you send it over the net: bandwidth is much more expensive than cpu-time, so your method `Array` to `UInt8Array` might be the best for you.